# Why is putting a lambda expression inside of a function call valid here?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm currently reading a book and I'm stuck right at the start of a particularly chapter. Because of where I'm stuck, [the context](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-10-in/9781098121945/ch09.html) can be found online without breaching the paywall. The relevant codeblock is this:

```cs
public class NutshellContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Customer");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired(); // Column is not nullable
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Purchase>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Purchase");
            entity.Property(e => e.Date).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.Description).IsRequired();
        });
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public virtual List<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
        = new List<Purchase>();
}

public class Purchase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The bit where I'm suck is here

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Customer");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired(); // Column is not nullable
});
```

My questions are as follows:

1. `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>` appears to be a function call. What does it mean to place a lambda expression inside a function call?
2. What is `entity` and why is it in scope? If it is just a free variable, then where in the documentation for `modelBuilder.Entity<T>` does it say that it can take such a construction as an input?
3. The above two questions, but for the `Property(e => e.Name)` piece of code.
4. If `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>` isn't a function call, then what is it?

Comment: c# will keep anthing a lambda function needs in scope, magically.

Comment: It means that the function expects as parameter an Action (for 1 and 2) or a Function (for 3 and 4) which are special types of delegates. A lambda expression is just a short way of creating an inline function and assigning it to the delegate. Lambda expressions are just “syntactic sugar”.

Comment: @CristianRusanu So even though there's nothing saying that the statement-bodied lambda expression following `entity =>` is an `Action`, the compiler magically knows that it is one? How?

Comment: @CristianRusanu I'm convinced for 1 and 2, but no overload of `entity.Property` accepts a delegate (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-6.0 ) so I'm still confused about `entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired()`.

Comment: [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-modelbuilder-entity-1(system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder((-0))))))

Comment: For property you link docs for EntityTypeBuilder, but in the code the derivered type `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` is used. It has overload for `Property` which accepts `Experssion<Func<T, TProperty>>`, this is the one being used. Now, lambda functions are NOT just syntactic sugar for delegates, because depending on context it can be converted either to delegate or to expression tree. In this case `Property` expects expression tree (`Expression<...>` type), and so lambda is converted to it. You can read online about expression trees in C#.

Comment: In general to clarify those points you can read documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: @Evk The only overload for `Property` that I'm seeing which accepts `Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>>` is `Property<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>>)`. How do you know that the call to `Property` is actually a call to `Property<TProperty>`? I don't see any `<>` near the call to `Property` in the code I've posted.

Comment: Compiler can deduce the overload from context in this case. You pass it lambda with one argument and which returns string. The only overload which can accept this is the one with Expression. Then compiler can deduce generic arguments from there so you don't have to specify them explicitly.

Comment: @Evk Don't suppose you can find a documentation link supporting that? It's a new idea to me. If so, you've got a perfectly solid answer.

Comment: How overload resolution works exactly is a very complicated subject. You can read the docs for example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1164-overload-resolution. However on practice it almost always works as you expect, finding the best candidate if possible, so you only need to dig into details if curious. I mean in your situation there is no ambiguity and only one overload can match, so it's not surprising it is being chosen.

Comment: This is really asking about basic C# and .NET programming but masquerading as an EF question. Similar questions could be asked of any API that uses lambdas, and as a whole these don't add value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the method (`modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>`) is the following (Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-modelbuilder-entity-1(system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder((-0))))))):

```
public virtual Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder Entity<TEntity> (Action<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>> buildAction) where TEntity : class;
```

What's relevant for us is the argument `buildAction`. It's type is `Action<EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>>`.

`Action<T>` [is defined as](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0) `public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);`

This means that Action is just a function that takes an argument of type T and returns nothing.

With [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) we can create anonymous functions, so with `entity => { ... }` we are just creating an anonymous function that takes in an argument that we decide to name `entity` and its scope will be the body of our expression (so what's inside of `{...}`).

The type of argument `entity` is inferred by the compiler because it knows that, as stated above, the argument of `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>` is Action<**EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>**>. So `entity` will be an instance of [EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1?view=efcore-7.0) therefore we can use methods like `ToTable`

About `Property(e => e.Name)` things are a little bit more complicated...
The method signature is the following (Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.property?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-1-property-1(system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-0))))))):

```
public virtual Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.PropertyBuilder<TProperty> Property<TProperty> (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>> propertyExpression);
```

Again, what's relevant for us is the argument `propertyExpression`. It's type is `Expression<Func<TEntity,TProperty>>`.

This means that it is an [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=net-7.0) that describes a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-7.0) (very similar to the Action described above, but instead of returning nothing it returns a value) that takes in an argument (that in our case we arbitrarily name `e`) of type `TEntity` and returns a value of type `TProperty`.

Both `TEntity` and `TProperty` are inferred by the compiler: We said above that `entity` is an instance of `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>`, so the inference made above by the compiler to determine `TEntity` is still valid now because we are calling an instance method of `entity`.

`TProperty` is inferred from the lambda expression `e => e.Name`. This expression is equivalent to `e => { return e.Name; }`.

Basically this lambda expression is a function that takes in an instance of `Customer` and returns its property `Name`. In the definition of the class Customer we declared Name as string so the compiler knows that `TProperty` is `string`.

But remember that the parameter we are passing to the method `Property`(`Property(e => e.Name)`) is just an `Expression`, not actually a function. Basically the code `e.Name` will never be run because it is not a compiled function. The compiler will emit an expression tree describing what we actually wrote (see [Remarks section of Expression class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=net-7.0#remarks)).

Then Entity Framework will parse the expression to determine the Property of your class that it will need to map in the Model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>` is a function it has such signature `Entity<TEntity>(Action<EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>>)` so basically it accepts other 'function' (here it's a delegate Action)

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-6.0):

> This overload allows configuration of the entity type to be done in
> line in the method call rather than being chained after a call to
> `Entity<TEntity>()`. This allows additional configuration at the model
> level to be chained after configuration for the entity type.

So it's basically configures entity you've passed.

`entity` is the name of parameter `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>` it's not a `free` variable. This param will be passed inside the lambda you specified during run time by the EF

Here with `e => e.Name` you are choosing which property you want change

`entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();`

`modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>` It is a function call

Comment: Which overload of `Property` is being called? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.property?view=efcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

It's just an overload method/configuration of the entity type that accepts an Action or a Function as delegate.

In the earlier version of EF, we do this by chaining:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customer").Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
```

That's just the same with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Customer");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired(); // Column is not nullable
});
```

But as the documentation says, this allows us to add additional configuration at the model level to be chained after configuration for the entity type.

But it generally doing the same thing, it configures the model that was discovered from the entity types exposed in DBSet properties: that your Customer entity resides in Customer table from your database and the property Name is required.

To understand further and to answer your #1 and #2 questions, consider this:

```
Action<EntityTypeBuilder<Customer>> expression = (entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Customer");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired(); // Column is not nullable
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(expression);
```

Entity method is expecting a delegate, lambda expression is just used to create an Action delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the most advanced guy in dotnet but from a noob point of view I'll answer what you want with a simple phrase : Scaffolding
this is an example my friend

1. Scaffolding

When we use scaffolding with a command line EntityFramework generate in your context file this bit of code.

2. After Generation of Code by the command

The modelBuilder.Entity here is **the DBSet** I declared AOC in **my Context file**.

Now the entity represent the Table I created in my local SQL and want to be created here in the code ( rever engineering Database first then code)

**Property(e => e.Opt)** 
**Property** means to access the properties you have in your table 
**e => e.Opt** : a link expression it means that this entity AOC (Table)
**`modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>`**  configuration of a given entity/Table Customer

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<AOC>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("AOC");

                entity.Property(e => e.Opt)
                    .HasMaxLength(2)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

            });
```